# Android - Pushes not received after the app is closed in parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have not received push on my device Xiaomi redmi 2. In other device receiving the push function normally even with the app closed.

I tested on a Samsung device and it worked perfectly, I could not understand why no notification arrives on my device

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

java:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, "us5HP0AWX4sdyHA1zjJEW6HdF9akjURdOIr1cAVF", "XunSChL6PglIFwfhP7AYyZ1UkHMpJ2Q98vZjjdqp");

        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        final ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Change this line: <category android:name="com.parse.starter" /> Change: `com.parse.starter` to something different!